# ¿Como calcular la edad mediante el campo de fecha en Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Quiero intentar calcular la edad en `Vue` mediante el campo de la base de datos fecha de nacimiento.

Según he leído debería hacer el cálculo en el `computed`, lo he intentado de la siguiente forma:

```
computed: {
    edad () {
        edad = Date.now - this.fecha_nac
    },           
},
```

Pero no me imprime ningún valor.

También he intentado ponerlo en el methods:

```
 methods: {          
    listar() {                
        let me = this;
        axios.get('api/Alumnos/Activos').then(function(response) {
            //console.log(response);                         
            me.alumnos=response.data;                       
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });                    
    },
    edad (edad) {
        edad = Date.now - this.fecha_nac
    },
}
```

Pero no me lo reconoce.

Soy nuevo en `Vue`, ¿podrían orientarme un poco?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: En que momento estas cambiando la fecha_nac como para que se ejecute tu computada?

Comment: No lo estoy contemplando sino solo en el Method con el llamado de axios. Creo que debo empezar de analizar desde allí.

Comment: En ningun momento estas llamando ni siquiera a ese metodo. Creo que hay un problema mas de fondo en lo que planteas que solamente eso. Esto esta explicado en la documentacion de vue. La leiste?

Comment: Di mi respuesta entendiendo que lo que quieres hacer es actualizar o agregar el campo edad a la matriz alumnos que cargas con la solicitud de Axios, creas un método que haga el calculo con la fecha actual del sistema (equipo de usuario, dado que es JS) y la fecha de nacimiento que entiendo viene de la solicitud

Answer (score 1):

La solución para el calculo de la diferencia entre fechas es simple, para manipulación de fechas en JavaScript usa [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```js
var fecha1 = moment('2000-08-12');
var fecha2 = moment('2019-09-01');

console.log(fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'years'), ' años de diferencia');
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

El método [`diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) te permite hallar la diferencia en cualquier unidad y la sintaxis es

```
moment.diff(moment, 'intervalo')
```

Para calcular lo mismo pero en horas

```js
var fecha1 = moment('2019-08-12');
var fecha2 = moment('2019-09-01');

console.log(fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'hours'), ' horas de diferencia');
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Ahora bien, vamos a tu caso.

Veo que estás guardando los datos de tus `alumnos` en un `array`, que supongo que está en el `data`; por ahora omitiré esa parte dado que supongo que entendiste el tema de las matrices en `JavaScript` y el tema de las variables con `Vue.js`.

Con la información que ya te dí puedes crear un método tal que así:

```js
methods: {
   CalcularEdad(fechaNacimiento){
      let nacimiento = moment(fechaNacimiento); //Debe estar en formato YYYY-MM-DD
      let hoy = moment();
      let edad = 0;
      if(nacimiento < hoy){
         edad = hoy.diff(nacimiento, 'years'); //Calculamos la diferencia en años
      }else{
         console.error("La fecha de nacimiento no puede ser superior a la fecha actual del sistema.");
      }
      return edad; //retornamos el resultado
   } 
}
```

Y ya con esto solo debes llamar el método así:

```js
//Recorro todos los datos que hay en la matriz de alumnos y llamo el método de calcular edad enviando la fecha de nacimiento para actualizar el campo de la edad de cada uno de los registros de alumnos dentro de la matriz
for(var i in this.alumnos){
   this.alumnos[i].edad = this.CalcularEdad(this.alumnos[i].fechaNacimiento)
}
```

Espero que esto solucione tu problema.